# sqlBuddy doesn't accept this .sql file to import

Tags: mysql, sql, apache, import, sqlbuddy

I would like to know why is this: backup.sql file not being accepted by [sqlBuddy](http://sqlbuddy.com/), I already created a database named youhand with utf8

sqlBuddy message:

```
0 statements were executed from the file.
The following errors were reported:
- No database selected
- No database selected
- No database selected
- No database selected
- No database selected
- No database selected
- No database selected
- No database selected
- No database selected
- No database selected
```

File Content:

```
--
-- MySQL 5.0.92
-- Mon, 14 May 2012 18:16:43 +0000
--



    CREATE TABLE `comentarios` (
       `id` int(7) not null auto_increment,
       `texto` varchar(500) not null,
       `id_usuario` int(7) not null,
       `id_receta` int(7) not null,
       `fecha` timestamp not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
       PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=24;


    CREATE TABLE `etiquetas` (
       `id` int(11) not null auto_increment,
       `nombre` varchar(50) not null,
       `id_usuario` int(7) not null,
       `id_pregunta` int(7) not null,
       `lan` int(3) not null,
       `id_consejo` int(7) not null,
       PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=122;

    CREATE TABLE `familias` (
       `id` int(7) not null auto_increment,
       `clave` varchar(100) not null,
       `pagina` varchar(3000) not null,
       `lan` int(2) not null,
       `id_padre` int(7) not null,
       `id_usuario` int(7) not null,
       PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=11;


    CREATE TABLE `follows` (
       `id` int(11) not null auto_increment,
       `toid` int(11) not null,
       `fromid` int(11) not null,
       PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=43;


    CREATE TABLE `idiomas` (
       `id` int(11) not null auto_increment,
       `lan` varchar(2) not null,
       `nombre` varchar(25) CHARSET utf8 not null,
       `url` varchar(100) not null,
       PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5;

    CREATE TABLE `notificaciones` (
       `id` int(11) not null auto_increment,
       `id_usuario` int(11),
       `id_from` int(11),
       `msj` varchar(1000),
       `tipo` int(2) default '0',
       `id_item` int(11) default '0',
       `leida` int(1) default '0',
       `tipo_actividad` int(2),
       PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2;

    CREATE TABLE `helps` (
       `id` int(11) not null auto_increment,
       `titulo` varchar(100) not null,
       `extra` varchar(3000) not null,
       `id_usuario` int(7) not null,
       `id_cultura` int(7) not null,
       `id_familia` int(7) not null,
       `req` text int(2) not null,
       `req_done` int(2) not null,
       `img_src` varchar(200) not null,
       `fecha` timestamp not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
       `votos` int(7) not null,
       `lan` int(3) not null,
       PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=63;

    CREATE TABLE `textos` (
       `id` int(7) not null auto_increment,
       `clave` varchar(100) not null,
       `texto` varchar(3000) not null,
       `lengua` int(3) not null,
       `id_usuario` int(7) not null,
       PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=664;

    CREATE TABLE `usuarios` (
       `id` int(7) not null auto_increment,
       `fid` bigint(60) not null,
       `alias` varchar(50) not null,
       `pass` varchar(100) not null,
       `mail` varchar(50) not null,
       `fechar` timestamp not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
       `ultima` timestamp not null default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
       `img_src` varchar(200) not null,
       `reputacion` int(11) not null,
       `lan` int(3) not null,
       PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=81;

    CREATE TABLE `votos_item` (
       `id` int(7) not null auto_increment,
       `tipo` int(3) not null,
       `valor` int(2) not null,
       `id_usuario` int(7) not null,
       `id_item` int(7) not null,
       `fecha` timestamp not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
       PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it does not know in what database to execute these statements.

- Either begin the file with a `use youhand;`
- Put a database name in front of each table name (so `CREATE TABLE youhand.familias`)
- Or start your application so that a database is chosen (commandline parameter or via the GUI)

Comment: Yes that was it. just realised. I was importing instead of navigating to the database and clicking the import option in the top navigation (for the database) menu. thanks!

Comment: hey!! OMG. i got the same problem as you guys over here. So @Konerak, I already tried your steps. but ended with no good result. Any ideas?

Comment: Hello @gumuruh! Since this question is almost two years old, maybe you should ask a new question instead. Post what you are trying to do, what you expect, what (error) you get instead, and what you already tried to solve it. We'll take it from there and help you!